# Rails 3.1 app can't install sqlite3 gem because libraries are out of date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, centos, sqlite3-ruby

The latest SQLite3 library available on CentOS 5.6 and which is installed is version 3.3.6.  It's my understanding that the sqlite3 gem needs version 3.6 or higher.

How do I get my app to work with SQLite3 without upgrading the library on my server?  It's in a work environment and I'm simply not allowed to upgrade it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could compile a static library of the version of sqlite you require.  Then install the sqlite3 gem with a reference to your new static library.

While I haven't tested this procedure, I could see the process being...

**1. Download and extract the SQLite source in a new directory.**

```
mkdir $HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1
cd $HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
tar -zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3070701
```

**2. Configure, compile, and install.**

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1
make && make install
```

**3.A. (option1) Install the SQLite gem with a reference to your new static lib.**

```
gem install sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1
```

**3.B. (option2) Install via bundler.  *Assuming sqlite3 has already been added to the Gemfile** (*thanks to Lester*)

```
bundle config build.sqlite3 \
  --with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1/include \
  --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1/lib \
  --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1/bin
bundle install
```

Comment: I had to customize the install with bundler like so `bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/bin`.  Then just had to run `bundle install` and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

The steps worked for me with one minor tweak.  With gem 1.3.7 and rails 3.1.0 for step 3.A. I had to do:

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1 --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/sqlite3.7.7.1/lib
```

the extra "--" in the middle allowed option to not be parsed by the gem file

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a MacBook which had some different versions of sqlite3 that had accumulated over the years.

For me, the gem install was:

gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/path/to/sqlite3/directory

In other words, I did only have to list the main sqlite3 development directory, but I did have to use the extra "--".

This allowed the installation of Rails 3.1 under Max OS X Lion